# modify variable for both getter and setter

Tags: c#

The following property just begs for a value being calculated once for both getter and setter

So instead of:

```
public bool this[int x, int y]
{
    get
    {
        return this[x * this.width + y];
    }
    set
    {
        this[x * this.width + y] = value;
    }
}
```

It be better if we could do this:

```
public bool this[int x, int y]
{
    int index = x * this.width + y;

    get
    {
        return this[index];
    }
    set
    {
        this[index] = value;
    }
}
```

In this case it's not such a big deal and an inline method could be used. But as a principle, is there a way?

Answer (score 5):

The `get` and `set` property accessors are actually compiled to two independent methods. If you need common code, you'll have to do it the same way as with any two different methods - by introducing a third method, possibly a static one.

```
private static CalculateIndex(int x, int width, int y)
{
    return x * width + y;
}

public bool this[int x, int y]
{
    get
    {
        return this[CalculateIndex(x, this.width, y)];
    }
    set
    }
        this[CalculateIndex(x, this.width, y)] = value;
    }
}
```

You cannot simply set a variable in this case so that it'd be common to the indexer's accessors, but if the calculation is really demanding, you may use some kind of caching, in which case you would access the cache in your accessors (just like the `index` variable in your example). The problem with this is that a cache is really heavyweight solution, you would have to handle checking if a value is cached, calculating it if it isn't and in some cases also removing it from the cache (especially to avoid memory leaks).

Comment: what is a difference between OP's presented question and this answer, from the *actual* issue prespective ?

Comment: The difference is that OP wanted to define something in the "scope" of the property, which I explained is not possible.

Comment: he *seems* to be complaining about a fact that he has to compute that value twice...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do the calculation twice, then add a helper method.

```
int GetOffset(int x, int y)
{
    return x + this.width * y;
}

public bool this[int x, int y]
{
    get
    {
        return this[GetOffset(x, y)];
    }
    set
    {
        this[GetOffset(x, y)] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May be something like this:

```
public bool this[int x, int y]
{    
    get
    {
        var index= x * this.width + y; //CALCULATE INDEX ON GET
        return this[index];
    }
    set
    {
        var index= x * this.width + y;//CALCULATE INDEX ON SET
        this[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is having to do the calculation twice.

Comment: @MrFox: I understamd what do you mean. In this case you need provide some sort of cashing strategy. But thing is thet *index* is a **computed** value, so untill you haven't computed it yet, you can not say if it same as was before or not. So, the caching, or identification of "value changed" state, imo, hast to be done somewhere outside of this property.